# How to get traffic log history from a relay?

Tags: relays, log

I'm currently running a TOR Relay. 
I'm monitoring it with nyx and is pretty good because I can see every connection coming in and out from my relay. 
But what I'm asking is how can I find a full list of all past connections to my node. 
Just in case someone (police?) ask me to give information about a certain IP I want to query this log for get this data. 
Is that possible? What I have to do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Neither Nyx nor Tor support this out of the box.

However you can do this with the [Stem](https://stem.torproject.org) library using the [connection API](https://stem.torproject.org/api/util/connection.html).

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of Tor is to anonymize it's users.

If you are running an exit relay, you do not know the client IP and have nothing to tell anyone because their request was relayed through a guard and middle node.

If you're running a guard and can see client addresses, any abuse request will never make it back to you because the public IP in question will be the exit.

So for the sake of the community, please don't keep any Tor connection logs.  If you run an exit and aren't prepared to deal with possible abuse reports, subpoenas, or other requests for information then consider switching to a guard or relay only and don't allow exit traffic.